# beaglebone black kernel module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to follow the walkthrough/tutorial found [here](http://dumb-looks-free.blogspot.ca/2014/06/beaglebone-black-bbb-kernal-headers.html).

I'm running kernel version `4.1.1-ti-r2`, which doesn't appear to have any header files in the `rcn-ee.net/deb/trusty-armhf` folder. This means that I can't make it past the first step. If I had the linux header files for my kernel, I could skip this step and move forward.

I can't just skip this step, since I don't have a `/lib/modules/4.1.1-ti-r2/build` directory.

So my question is this. How can I generate the linux header files that I need? I'm relatively inexperienced with `Linux/Ubuntu`, so baby steps are appreciated.

Comment: You have to ask TI (or whoever modified that kernel) to provide the full sources to you. Or try find them by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write drivers for BBB then this is the best resource: 
http://derekmolloy.ie/writing-a-linux-kernel-module-part-1-introduction/

Here you will find the steps required for the header installation.